# retrieving data from many to many using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have 2 table and a pivot table. structure of the table is mentioned below.

```
users table:
id username password
1   admin    xyzasd

roles table:

id  name
1   role1
2   role2

role_user table:

id user_id role_id
1    1       1
2    1       2
```

My user model:

```
class User extends Basemodel{
    public static $table = 'users';
    public static $timestamps = true;

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Role');
    }

    public static function menu(){
        $roles = User::find(1)->roles()->get();
        return $roles;
    }
}
```

my controller:

```
public function get_index()
    {
        return View::make('home.index')
            ->with('title','testing many to many')
            ->with('menu',User::menu());
    }
```

and in my blade view file i have this statement {{$menu}} all i get is a message array, can some one guide me on how to fetch the records ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, User should extend Eloquent. Also, you should create a Role model.

//application/models/User.php

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public static $table = 'users';
    public static $timestamps = true;

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Role');
    }
}
```

//application/models/Role.php

```
class Role extends Eloquent
{
    public static $table = 'roles';
    public static $timestamps = true;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('User');
    }
}
```

Then for your controller you basically can just pass the user.

```
public function get_index()
{
    $user = User::find(1);

    return View::make('home.index')
        ->with('title','testing many to many')
        ->with('user', $user);
}
```

Then in your view you can do cool stuff like:

```
<h1>What's up {{ $user->username }}?</h1>
<h2>You have the following roles:</h2>
@foreach($user->roles as $role)
    <p>{{ $role->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: i have extended the eloquent class in my Basemodel. :) but really thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over `$menu` array in your view:

```
@foreach ($menu as $menu_item)
  {{ $menu_item->id }} # output ID of a record
@endforeach
```